# Way to install mdm certificates programmatically in app

Tags: ios, mdm

this may sound a bit dodge, but im working on a parental app/browser lockdown app, and the use of the mdm service is basically the functionality i need, but i want the users to be able to control the mdm services for their childs device through a website.

I have everything working, except at the moment im not sure if there is a way to actually install the certificates needed programmatically in my app. I can do it manually through safari, but that detracts from the apps experience.

I basically want to mimic the functionality safari gives when downloading these certs but in my app.

has anyone tried something like this before?

alternatively, is there a way to get a UIWebView to respond to the mime-type of application/x-x509-ca-cert and application/x-apple-aspen-config ?

Comment: Do you need this certificate to securely communicate to the server? Do you need this certificate only for your app or you want to install it to device trusted store (so all apps trust to this web site). Are you aware of InstallProfile MDM command (you can install a certificate through MDM)

Comment: im trying to enroll the device into the mdm service via the app, the process requires you to download some certificates, i can download these certificates through safari and it sets it up and it works, but im not sure how to handle them within my app.

Answer (score 3):

My knowledge of this could be outdated because I tried this on iOS 5.X. So, be aware.

At that moment, you weren't allowed to install certificates from your application (so UIWebView with application/x-x509-ca-cert didn't work). I believe an app should have special entitlement (which only system apps can have) to install a certificate to iOS' trusted certs store.

I believe the same is true for configuration profile installation via UIWebView.
By the way, here is an old discussion about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iphonesdkdevelopment/8QDPE1juB2g

However, I think you should try it now. Things could have changed.

Now, regarding installation of configuration profiles through Safari. I am not sure whether you are doing this completely manual or semi-manual, but just in case if you are doing this completely manual, here is the code which will allow you to partially automate it.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"<URLOfPageWhichHasConfigProfile>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication openURL: url];
```

This will switch to Safari, which will switch to Preferences after that and after user approval it will get back to Safari. I know, it's not perfect.

Comment: yeah, not perfect, but probably the only option